# Why does my fake constant assignment only work once in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, google-maps-markers

I'm using gomap to add some markers to a map. gomap allows you to add an icon of your choosing rather than being stuck with the same old marker. I have several bits of code like this:

```
var constants = {
    'nflIcon': 'Content/Images/green.png',
    'bigBurrito': 'Content/Images/humongousBurrito.png'
};

$(function () {
    $("#map").goMap({
        latitude: 36.75,
        longitude: -100,
        maptype: 'ROADMAP',
        zoom: 5
    });

$.goMap.createMarker({
    address: 'Green Bay, Wisconsin',
    title: 'Green Bay Packers',
    group: 'NFL',
    icon: constants.nflIcon,
    html: getPackers()
});

$.goMap.createMarker({
    address: 'San Francisco, California',
    title: 'San Francisco 49ers',
    group: 'NFL',
    icon: constants.nlfIcon,
    html: '<h1>San Francisco 49ers</h1>'
});
```

...but the assignment of constants.nflIcon only works one (with the Green Bay Packers marker); allthe others use the traditional orange reverse teardrop marker.

Why?

Comment: It probably has to do with `nfl` vs. `nlf` in your two examples. :-)  When in doubt, copy and paste from the one that is working to the one that is not (and then remove the need for copy-pasting by abstracting the call away).

Comment: Heavens to Murgatroid! I'm not a Dyslexic, but I play one on the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `nlfIcon` in your non-working call and `nflIcon` in your working call:

```
$.goMap.createMarker({
    address: 'San Francisco, California',
    title: 'San Francisco 49ers',
    group: 'NFL',
    icon: constants.nflIcon, // This is now fixed
    html: '<h1>San Francisco 49ers</h1>'
});
```

If I was going to be doing this frequently, I'd create a wrapper around `createMarker` to simplify my code.  For example, you might do the following:

```
function createMarker(options) {
    var defaults = {icon: constants.nflIcon};
    $.goMap.createMarker($.extend({}, defaults, options));
}

function createNFLMarker(options) {
    var defaults = {group: "NFL"};
    createMarker($.extend({}, defaults, options));
}
```

Then you can call `createNFLMarker` with the details that change for each team (address, title, etc.), rather than having to keep multiple sections of copy-pasted code in sync.

Comment: This is the solution... :) A good idea is to open console(F12 in most browsers) to check for errors before you even start to think where the problem lies - I bet you would get null reference exception in this case.

Comment: @Alexus - in this case just `undefined`.  JavaScript is pretty easy-going.

Comment: Yeah, I am more of a C# guy :)